# SASS target :before tag if another class is present

Tags: sass

I'm trying to modify a ::before tag that contains another class.

```
HTML
<div class="foo active">
   <div>...</div>
</div>

SCSS
.foo {
 &:before {
   content: "";
   border-top: 3px solid $grey;
   width: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-10px);

   &:first-child {
     border-top: none;
   }

   &.active { // attempt 1
     border: 3px solid $primary;
   }
 }

 &:before.active { // attempt 2
   border: 3px solid $primary;
 }
}
```

I'm trying to modify the :before top border only if the active class is present. What else can I try?

Comment: Try `&.active:before`.

Comment: @Bauke Thanks that did it. If you would like to add that as an answer I'll accept it.